# Reference for very basic books in Measure theory

Tags: measure-theory

Im confused  which books i have to read for measure theory for beginner

Reference for  very basic books  in Measure theory 
 that Book  must contain given Topics below

$1.$Lebesgue measure

$2.$ measurable functions

$3.$Lebesgue integral

$4.$ Fatou’s lemma

$5.$monotone convergencetheorem

$6$ Dominated convergence theorem

Comment: You might take a look at: 1) [Measure, Integration, and Real Analysis](http://measure.axler.net/) by Sheldon Axler (author of Linear Algebra Done Right, a very popular linear algebra book) ; [Wheeden and Zygmund](https://www.amazon.com/Measure-Integral-Introduction-Analysis-Mathematics/dp/0824764994) ; [Royden](https://www.amazon.com/Analysis-Classic-Classics-Advanced-Mathematics/dp/0134689496/ref=sr_1_1?dchild=1&keywords=royden&qid=1590945307&s=books&sr=1-1);  The final two chapters of Analysis II by Terence Tao.

Comment: thanks u sir @littleO

Comment: @littleO Okay but that math font on the cover . . . had me gagging (in the bad way)

Comment: I really like [Stein's book](https://www.amazon.com/Real-Analysis-Integration-Princeton-Lectures/dp/0691113866) on these topics. (It is the third book in a four-book series on analysis.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a nice introduction which has the benefit of being short, I really like Bartle's "Measure Theory" as a first book. Another book which is good on intuition, though somewhat nonstandard at times, is Tao's "An Introduction to Measure Theory". Finally, I would be shamed if I did not recommend the relevant sections in Rudin's "Real and Complex Analysis" as well as Folland's "Real Analysis" - though I warn these should be read *after* looking at the first two, since they are faster paced, and delve deeper into the topic.

---

I hope this helps ^_^